# When the player collides with the monster the lives are not reducing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have now added lives into my game and it was working fine when using just text. However, now that I have changed it to images, it's not working. The images (hearts x3) are displaying but are not reducing when the player collides with the monster.
UPDATE: full game loop now included!

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1]+32, 32, 32)
        self.image = playerImg
        self.lives = 3
```

```
def life_dis(screen,x,y,lives,img):
    for i in range(lives):
        img_rect = img.get_rect()
        img_rect.x = x+37*i
        img_rect.y = y
        screen.blit(img, img_rect)
```

```
def game_loop():
    global walls, players, monsters, finishes, currentLevel
    level = 1 #Starting level
    running = True
    while running:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.fill(blue)        
        level_dis(level)

        #Move the player if an arrow key is pressed
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            player.move(-2, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            player.move(2, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            player.move(0, -2)
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            player.move(0, 2)

        #Move monster
        for monster in monsters:
            monster.move()

        #Moving to next level/win
        for player in players:
            for finish in finishes:
                if player.rect.colliderect(finish.rect):
                    if currentLevel < Highest_level:
                        currentLevel +=1
                        level +=1
                        walls, players, monsters, finishes = load_level(currentLevel)
                    else:
                        win()
                        level = 1
                        #lives = 3

        #Getting caught by the monster
        for player in players:
            for monster in monsters:
                if player.rect.colliderect(monster.rect):
                    load_current_level()
                    player.lives -=1
                    if player.lives == 0:
                        game_over()
                        level = 1
                        #lives = 3

        #Draw the scene
        screen.blit(background, (0,32))
        for wall in walls:
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, wall.rect)
            screen.blit(wall.image, wall.rect)
        for player in players:
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange, player.rect)
            screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)
        for monster in monsters:
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, bright_green, monster.rect)
            screen.blit(monster.image, monster.rect)
        for finish in finishes:
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, finish.rect)
            screen.blit(finish.image, finish.rect)
        life_dis(screen,500,0,player.lives,lifeImg)
        pygame.display.update()
```

That's the snippets from my code showing how I have set up the 'lives'. I probably haven't declared something or not in the right place! I don't think it's a display update thing either as the game should end once the monster has got you 3 times but it's not. Thanks in advance for any help and I can provide the whole code if required.

Comment: The indentation of the code from `for player in players:` onward appears to be messed-up, so it's difficult to determine what's going on. Please [edit] your question and fix this.

Comment: Not sure how that happened but now corrected! In my actual file all the indentation is correct so it must have become wrong when I copied it to here.

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit didn't tell me as much as I hoped. What is `player` in the next-to-last line: `life_dis(screen,500,0,player.lives,lifeImg)`

Comment: That is calling the ```self.lives = 3``` from the player class.

Comment: I assume that `player` is some _instance_ of the `Player` class, not the class itself (which wouldn't make much sense anyway)…and I can't determine what instance the code currently in your question refers to. You probably need to add more code to your question in order for anyone to help you.

Comment: After seeing the code you added to your question, I think I see the problem. The call to `life_dis(screen,500,0,player.lives,lifeImg)` near the end _isn't_ inside a `for player in players:` loop, so the value of `player` will be whatever it was the last time a loop like that was executed — most likely not what you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it works in text I suspect that it is a screen updating issue. If your hearts is blitted on a part of the screen that isn't re-drawn each loop, the old image of the heart will remain on the screen even if you pass pygame.diaplsy.update().

Try to use screen.fill() before you draw everything on the screen to reset it.

Comment: Thanks. I have the screen.fill() earlier in the main game loop as otherwise you can't see what level you are on! I tried later in the loop and it made no difference to the hearts but hid the level info. I have now added the whole of the main game loop code in the hope that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved it! I removed `self.lives = 3` from the player class and made a global variable `lives = 3` instead. I then changed the `player.lives` to just `lives`, plus called `lives` under global in the main game loop and all works fine now!
Thanks for the suggestions as they did help me get to solving this problem. However, I would still be interested to know why it wasn't working before. Had I done something wrong or is just due to the way my game runs that it didn't work. Thanks again!